# Go vet command error

Tags: golang

Just updated the golang compiler to 1.12.5 version. Everything works just fine, apart from `go vet` command. It responds with the following error:

```
# runtime/cgo
_cgo_export.c:3:10: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I'm not sure where have I mistaken, but if You have some ideas, I'll be really grateful.

Comment: What version did you use before?

Comment: @grawity I believe, it was 1.7

Comment: If you are on alpine try installing `libc-dev`.

Comment: @VasanthaGaneshK yep! I've already solved this, and that a way I used